# How to use two kind of notes (alph and arabic) separated at the bottom and in the end of text?

Tags: footnotes, manyfoot

I'm trying to do two kinds of notes in my text:

1. The traditional footnote, using `\arabic` at the bottom of the page
2. a second kind of footnote, using `\alph` at the end of chapter or at the end of text, just to put the original text of my translated quotes.

I can do 1 *or* 2, but my problem is to do *both*.

I can do different levels of footnote with alph and arabic with the packages `manyfoot` and `bigfoot`. I can also send all the notes to the end or some kind of notes with `pagenote` and `endnote` packages. But the problem appears when I try to send the `\alph` notes (`\footnoteA`) to the end: then Gummi software shows me *all* notes in `\arabic`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{endnotes} 
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\usepackage[perpage,ruled,para]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]
    \renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA}}

% Just swicth the following line "let\footnoteA=\endnote" on/off to 
%  see the results. When I send footnoteA alph to the end, 
% it displays arabic instead of alph
\let\footnoteA=\endnote

\begin{document}

Bla for /footnote \footnote{We have the /footnote}

Bla for /footnoteA \footnoteA{Then we have /FootnoteA.}

Just an /endnote \endnote{then, /endnote}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: To clarify what was going on, the `\let\footnoteA=\endnote` line renders subsequent `\footnoteA` calls *equivalent* to an `\endnote` call, negating the preceding declaration. Your answer below is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

After two unsuccessfull days trying different complicated codes configuration, the answer was much more simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\alph{footnote}} 

\begin{document}

Text
    \footnote{ the normal footnote} 
Text
    \endnote{And the endnote.} 

    \clearpage 
    \theendnotes 
    \end{document}
```

However, this solution does not display the sequence correctly. It shows something like "a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c," instead of "a,b,c,d,e...". The solution is to use the package `enotez` instead of `endnote` since the former is an improvement of the later. So the new code becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\setenotez{counter-format = alph} % <-- instead of \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\alph{footnote}} 

\begin{document}
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
    Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}.
    Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}.
    Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}.  
    Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}.  
    Sample text.\endnote{Sample endnote}.   
\printendnotes           % <-- instead of \theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Another advantage of `enotez` over `endnote` package is the possibility to use hyperreference Just adding

```
    \usepackage{hyperref}
```

in the preamble

Comment: It solved the problem only partially. A sequence of several `\endnote{}`  does not show correctly the sequence a,b,c,d… or 1,2,3… but  a,a,b,b, c,c,f,f,f,f,; sometimes a,a,a,a,.